# Matrix transposition without using loops..?

Tags: matrix

How to transpose a matrix without using any kind of loops. If it's nxn we can make the diagonal as base and shift elements. But for nxm matrix I think this solution is not feasible.

Anyway, to read or store we need to use loops right...??

Any solution without loops..??

Comment: What language is this for?  Or is it language-agnostic?  You could parameterise your matrix storage as row- or column-major, in which case to transpose you can simply switch from one to the other and swap the dimensions.

Comment: Why? (`catch CommentTooShortException`)

Answer (score 0):

If you have known at the beginning the dimension of the matrix, then you will not need any loop. Because you just can swap the matrix position to transpose the matrix overall. In this first condition you don't need loop as well even if the dimension is m x n.

But if you don't know the dimension of matrix in the beginning, then we definitely will need loop to iterate the matrix to read some position and swap to other position in process of transposing matrix.

Answer (score 0):

For storing the entire transposed matrix, you definitely need to use a loop. This is not really a big deal since storing a matrix uses loops anyway, as you need to loop through the members of the matrix to store it.

If you are just reading it, you can use the definition of a matrix transpose and just translate the indicies. For example, in C:

```
int getTransposedElement(int i,int j, int** originalMatrix) {
  return originalMatrix[j,i];
}
```

If you are using a language with classes and polymorphism, you can create a new matrix class that does this automatically. This has the additional benefit that it avoids copying the original matrix, which saves memory and allows changes to the transposed matrix to be reflected in the original matrix.